# Error when trying to view return values

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays

I've written the following contract

```
contract Catalog{
    address[] internal array;


    function pushItem(address _el) external{
         array.push(_el);
    }

    function getArray() external returns(address[]){
         return array;
    }
 }
```

I've deployed it on a local Javascript VM with Remix. Then I've called `pushItem(0x.....)` but, when I invoke `getArray()` the following output is returned:

`error: Failed to decode output: 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Any idea why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: How are u calling the contract? Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are incorrectly pushing to the array. When pushing an address you need to do it like so: `pushItem("0x...")`. You are currently pushing to the array like so: `pushItem(0x...)`. Also you may as well limit your `getArray() external` to `getArray() external view` since you're only looking at the data.